# FL Studio 12 automation chain

Tags: fl-studio

Is it possible in [FL Studio 12](https://www.image-line.com/flstudio/) create a chain of automation like so:

1. `Parametric EQ2`'s knob is being controlled by some external `LFO` source
2. This knob controls *another* knob in the **same** plugin instance

or like so:

1. `Parametric EQ2`'s knob is being controlled by some external `LFO` source
2. This knob controls *another* knob in **different** iVST/VST plugin like `WaveSharper` or something else

Answer (score 2):

A year and a half late but here's what you can do (hoping it is indeed what you asked for):

- Automate your first knob as usual.
- Right-click the second knob that you want to have follow the same automation.
- Select `Link to controller`.
- Under the `Internal controller` section, in the drop down, find the automation you created for the first knob.
- **Uncheck `Remove conflicts`** (or the first knob will be unlinked from its automation).
- Accept.

Now both knobs are following the same automation.
If you wish to link a same knob to more than one automation in the same way:

- Right-click your knob and `Link to controller` again
- Another drop down made its appearance at the top of the dialog. It should say `Link 1` or something similar. Select `New Link`.
- Select another automation from the `Internal controller` drop down (and don't forget to uncheck `Remove conflicts`)

Hope that helps. :)

Also, useful piece of info in case you don't know: when 3rd-party VST knobs are right-clicked, they will show a contextual menu defined by the VST, not FL Studio's usual menu. In order to find the `Create automation clip` option:

- Tweak the knob you wish to automate
- Navigate to FL Studio's `Tool` menu (top-left of the screen)
- `Last tweaked` > `Create automation clip`

This also works for `Link to controller` and any other option you'd expect to find in FL Studio's contextual menu.